# LyX and jlcode: subscript, superscript and other special characters

Tags: lyx, subscripts, superscripts, resolution, julia

I am trying [jlcode](https:////github.com/wg030/jlcode) within a LyX document in order to insert Julia codes. Here is an exemple of the .tex file in the case of an elementary program:

```
%% LyX 2.3.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\date{}

\usepackage[autoload=true]{jlcode}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{\noun{Using jlcode}}}

\maketitle
Here is an example of code: 

\begin{jllisting}[language=julia, style=jlcodestyle]

"""
This program describes the NMR spin-lattice relaxation kinetics
of a 1H spin system.
A comparison is made between the analytical solution and a
numerical solution using a Tsits5() solver.
"""

#Greek letters are imported from Julia REPL: α, β, γ, δ, ε, ...

using DifferentialEquations, Plots
 
#------------------------ data (S.I. units) ------------------
 t1 = 0.92 # relaxation time (s)
 u0 = -1.0 # initial normalized value of H0
 tspan = (0.0,5.0) # time scale (s)
 
#------------------------ analytical solution ----------------
 equation(u,p,t) = (1/t1)*(1.0-u)

#------------------------ numerical resolution ---------------
 probleme = ODEProblem(equation,u0,tspan) 
 solution = solve(probleme, Tsit5(), reltol=1e-8, abstol=1e-8)
 
#------------------------ graphs -----------------------------
 plot(solution) 
 plot!(solution.t, t->1.0-(2.0*exp(-t/t1))) 
 savefig("relaxation_T1-1HRMN_2.pdf")

\end{jllisting}
\end{document}
```

Initially I could not obtain Greek letters. I succeeded by changing  a setting in Lyx: Document --> Settings --> Language --> Others. I selected Unicode (utf8). The result is given in this picture:
[image]

**My question is**: how to obtain superscripts, subscripts and possibly others special math characters?
For instance, 1H should appear with 1 in superscript (as it represents an hydrogen atom). Similarly, in t1, 1 should appear as an subscript.

Although I know the method with TeX (e.g., t$_1$), with jlcode, I don't see how to proceed.
Can you guide me because the [jlcode manual](https:////github.com/wg030/jlcode/blob/master/manual.pdf) although giving a nice listing does not provide the method to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lyx, Documents --> Settings --> Language --> Others. Select **Unicode (XeTeX)(utf8)**.
Symbols, subscripts, superscripts can be copied/pasted from the REPL of Julia.